# jQuery get name attribute of any select input using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, select

**UPDATE**

How is what I am asking, different from this example from jQuery

```
<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
var color = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
$( "#result" ).html( "That div is <span style='color:" +
color + ";'>" + color + "</span>." );
});
</script>
```

I am building this parameter based search engine that when a person selects a value from a specific select box, that value is added to a text input which can be modified directly eg. typing.

I have that part, what I'm trying to solve is how to remove repeats eg. if someone decides to change the value that they had selected for one select input that they had already selected, the value should replace the old value.

I am trying to solve this by building a variable / instance of a list which ads on as more select fields are selected eg. have value.

What I tried to apply is **this**

So I have a select input like this -side note- I realize that onchange and onclick may be redundant if I can accomplish all in one but it's nice to know I have the option to use more than one.

```
<select name="name of select" id="id of select" onchange="changeFunc(value);" onclick="check();">
```

So I have this to create a variable / instance to append select values to

```
function addParameters(){
// build selected options list

function currentOptionsSelected(){
this.value = "";
}

var cOS = new currentOptionsSelected();

function updateCOS(fnc){

}

}
```

That is the plan once I get this to work

```
function check(){
var nameOfSelectBox = $(this).attr("name");
$( "select" ).click(function() {
var nameOfSelectBox = $( this ).attr("name");
var nameOfSelectBox = $('[name=" "]');
alert(nameOfSelectBox);
});
var nameOfSelectBox = $("select").attr("name");
alert(nameOfSelectBox);
updateCOS(fnc);
}
```

As you can see I was trying different methods.

So, I check with str.match() if the select name already has been used eg. selected and then I update the value

If there is a better way, suggestions are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: `this` is not set automatically when using inline event handlers

Comment: I wrote an update above, do you know anything about that? Maybe that is exactly what you said about inline event handlers. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Inside the `check()` function, just do `console.log(this)` to see what you've got, I'm guessing it's the window.

Comment: Oh wow... that was it, major noob mistake, check was inside addParameter()... I see said the non-blind man.  Thank you. If you'd like to post that as an answer so I can select it as such, you're welcome to. Thanks. I'm not yet for sure that I solved it, but an alert did appear with the select name

Comment: I'm not sure what to answer, but when you figure it out and have a working answer, you can post it yourself to help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

Her tis

```
$( "select" ).click(function() {
var nameOfSelectBox = $( this ).attr("name");
alert(nameOfSelectBox);
});
```

This alerts the person of what select box they clicked, then from here you create a variable of concatenated strings and append this to that string and then string.match() for the name of the select box in order to remove it and place a new one if the person changes the value. That's the idea anyway. Will have to see if I can do that.